# Matching values to return specific cell info

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one workbook two tabs. I have user info and device info in one and device info on the other. I want to populate 1st with user info if the two cells have identical info in. Example below:

Tab 1
[Table one software details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEgDt.png)

Tab 2
[Table two Device/user info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY8L8.png)

I want the user details in column to populate against each row that matches Device Hostname.

Comment: =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),2,4,1,"Sheet2"))

Comment: Where Sheet1!A1 is the device hostname; Sheet2A:A is the matching column to search; 2 is the column of username, 4=4, 1=1, "Sheet2" is the name of the other sheet.

Comment: Match finds the row, address builds a reference ie. A1, G7 etc...  Indirect uses the reference string as a location.

Answer (score 0):

=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),2,4,1,"Sheet2"))

Where Sheet1!A1 is the device hostname; Sheet2A:A is the matching column to search; 2 is the column of username, 4=4, 1=1, "Sheet2" is the name of the other sheet.

Match finds the row, address builds a reference ie. A1, G7 etc... Indirect uses the reference string as a location.

:)